# pandas rename multi-level column having the same name

Tags: python, pandas

When I use aggregate function, the resulting columns 'price' and 'carat' have the same column name of 'mean'.

How do i rename the `mean` under the `price` to `price_mean` and under `carat` to `carat_mean`.
I can't change them individually.

```
diamonds.groupby('cut').agg({
    'price': ['count', 'mean'],
    'carat': 'mean'
}).rename(columns={'mean':'price_mean','mean':'carat_mean'}, level = 1)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide data as text rather than image

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
# Rename columns of level 1
df1 = df["price"]
df1.columns = ["count", "carat_mean"]

df2 = df["carat"]
df2.columns = ["carat_mean"]

# Aggregate dfs (with renamed columns) under level 0 columns
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['price', 'carat'])

print(df)
# Outputs
          price                 carat
          count carat_mean carat_mean
Fair   0.693995  -0.632283   0.789963
Good   0.099057   1.005623   0.143289
Ideal -0.277984  -0.105138  -0.611168
```